# Background thread throws exception when unloading in AppDomain, how can I stop it? Error while uploading appdomain (HRESULT 0x80131015)

Tags: multithreading, background, appdomain, hresult

I've been using [this program](http://wyday.com/blog/2010/multi-process-c-sharp-application-like-google-chrome-using-named-pipes/).

I am currently running the server program in an appdomain. However, when I want to unload it, it returns an exception with HRESULT 0x80131015. This only occurs when I start the pipeServer by clicking the button. I've checked which threads are running and tried to abort them, but they just won't abort. Their status comes back as "abort requested."

```
  public void Start(string pipename)
        {
            PipeName = pipename;

            //start the listening thread
            listenThread = new Thread(ListenForClients)
                               {
                                   IsBackground = true
                               };

            listenThread.Start();

            Running = true;
        }

        void ListenForClients()
        {
            SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd = new SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR();

            // set the Security Descriptor to be completely permissive
            InitializeSecurityDescriptor(ref sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
            SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(ref sd, true, IntPtr.Zero, false);

            IntPtr ptrSD = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(sd));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(sd, ptrSD, false);

            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                         {
                                             nLength = Marshal.SizeOf(sd),
                                             lpSecurityDescriptor = ptrSD,
                                             bInheritHandle = 1
                                         };

            IntPtr ptrSA = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(sa));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(sa, ptrSA, false);


            while (true)
            {
                // Creates an instance of a named pipe for one client
                SafeFileHandle clientHandle =
                    CreateNamedPipe(
                        PipeName,

                        // DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000003 | 0x40000000;
                        0x40000003,
                        0,
                        255,
                        BUFFER_SIZE,
                        BUFFER_SIZE,
                        0,
                        ptrSA);

                //could not create named pipe instance
                if (clientHandle.IsInvalid)
                    continue;

                int success = ConnectNamedPipe(clientHandle, IntPtr.Zero);

                //could not connect client
                if (success == 0)
                {
                    // close the handle, and wait for the next client
                    clientHandle.Close();
                    continue;
                }

                Client client = new Client
                                    {
                                        handle = clientHandle
                                    };

                lock (clients)
                    clients.Add(client);

                Thread readThread = new Thread(Read)
                                        {
                                            IsBackground = true
                                        };
                readThread.Start(client);
            }

            // free up the ptrs (never reached due to infinite loop)
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptrSD);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptrSA);
        }

        void Read(object clientObj)
        {
            Client client = (Client)clientObj;
            client.stream = new FileStream(client.handle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, BUFFER_SIZE, true);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

            while (true)
            {
                int bytesRead = 0;

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // read the total stream length
                        int totalSize = client.stream.Read(buffer, 0, 4);

                        // client has disconnected
                        if (totalSize == 0)
                            break;

                        totalSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);

                        do
                        {
                            int numBytes = client.stream.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(totalSize - bytesRead, BUFFER_SIZE));

                            ms.Write(buffer, 0, numBytes);

                            bytesRead += numBytes;

                        } while (bytesRead < totalSize);

                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //read error has occurred
                        break;
                    }

                    //client has disconnected
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                        break;

                    //fire message received event
                    if (MessageReceived != null)

                        MessageReceived(ms.ToArray());
                }
            }

            // the clients must be locked - otherwise "stream.Close()"
            // could be called while SendMessage(byte[]) is being called on another thread.
            // This leads to an IO error & several wasted days.
            lock (clients)
            {
                //clean up resources
                DisconnectNamedPipe(client.handle);
                client.stream.Close();
                client.handle.Close();

                clients.Remove(client);
            }

            // invoke the event, a client disconnected
            if (ClientDisconnected != null)
                ClientDisconnected();
        }
```

This is some sample code which runs the two background threads.
Any help on how to unload the appdomain safely?

Comment: That's CannotUnloadAppDomainException.  That happens when the CLR cannot abort a thread that run in the AppDomain.  Like when it executes native code.  It is a fairly odd piece of code, no point in using pinvoke when you can use the System.IO.Pipes namespace.  Asking a thread to exit nicely is of course always better.

Comment: You are right, it is fairly odd, however, it is what I have to use at this point. I may just go for duplex named pipes. Also, how would I ask the thread to exit nicely? I am a beginner at this threading stuff, so please bear with me, thank you.